# Pegar imagem selecionada e enviar para outra Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, gridview

Gostaria de saber se é possivel pegar uma imagem selecionada e enviar para outra activity. Estou usando fragments e queria que o layout ficasse como na imagem abaixo.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria que quando o usuario selecionar a imagem, pegar esta e enviar para outra activity e apresentar na tela.
Class Fragment:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

GridView gridView;
int [] listaImagens = new int[]{R.drawable.eu, R.drawable.perguntas, R.drawable.respostas};
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup conteiner, Bundle saveInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_frag_1, conteiner, false);

    gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageFrag1);
    gridView.setAdapter(new Adaptador(view.getContext(), listaImagens));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Imagem " +listaImagens[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return (view);

}
```

}

Class Adapter:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

GridView gridView;
int [] listaImagens = new int[]{R.drawable.eu, R.drawable.perguntas, R.drawable.respostas};
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup conteiner, Bundle saveInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_frag_1, conteiner, false);

    gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageFrag1);
    gridView.setAdapter(new Adaptador(view.getContext(), listaImagens));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Imagem " +listaImagens[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return (view);

}
```

}

Comment: Acho que você errou ao colar o adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode passar a posição dela.

Exemplo:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Display_Image_Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("img", listaImagens[position]);
            getActivity().startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

No Activity você vai pegar o valor dela, que será por exemplo:

```
String img;

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
    img = extras.getString("img");
}

Resources res = getResources();
int resID = res.getIdentifier(img , "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(resID);

ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

A variável **img** terá o valor de **R.drawable.perguntas**, por exemplo.

Comment: Sua resposta está incompleta. Acho que ele quer saber também como receber esses dados em outra activity.

Comment: @seamusd Coloquei o complemento da segunda Activity, valeu pela dica

Comment: Você notou que ele diz que "...pegar esta e enviar para outra activity..." quando na verdade ele está em um Fragment. Como a pergunta ta mal formulada, você pensou nessas hipótese que ele pretende enviar de um fragment para um outro fragment?!

Comment: Verdade, não tinha reparado na confusão, editei a minha resposta, eu imagino que o primeiro caso seja um Fragment, e aonde irá receber os dados seja uma Activity

Comment: @seamusd me desculpe pela pergunta mal formulada e a todos que me ajudaram. Descobri como fazer o que queria com fragments.